# Set a field that increment automatically in core data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data

In databases like SqlServer we can set a field that increment automatically(Identity Increment),is it possible to do that in core data ?

Comment: What causes the counter to increment?  Save?  Insert??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think internal and automatic **auto increment** is not possible in Core Data.
You need to use custom solution for that.

Can you tell me what you're actually trying to do?

I had the same problem and I am using `NSUserDefault` to store my counter.

Comment: i have a field for code and want to set value for it automatically

Comment: and add this counter value into core data.

Comment: so take one int variable and add it into core data and keep it counte++;

Comment: i use a way like you now,but i want to do that automatically

Comment: ok now after adding this counter in your core data just do it counter++ and store at the NSUSerDefault and everytime when you wants to add this counter you need to fetch it from the NSUSerDefault.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a creationDate field. When you're creating your object simply add

```
NSDate *creationDate = [NSDate date];
```

Very simple to sort on an NSDate, convert it to a double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a field that auto increments upon inserts, that is not possible with Core Data afaik. You will have to come up with a custom solution. Which solution depends on the problem you try to solve.

Core Data does maintain a unique object ID (or URI) for each object that is persisted with Core Data. There's a more on object ID's and URI's [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html).

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible, but perhaps not in the way you are thinking about it.
:) -- meaning , not as a 'key' field.

you can create a 'counter' `NSManagedObject`, that is initialized at the app's launch and is there after tracking a '**current number**' and '**next number**' property when it is asked to do so.

you can retrieve the current number and assign that as a property value for an object that needs to have this unique and incremented '**number**'.

there is a sample code '**iClass**' that i can't find a link for on apple.com, but was installed with Xcode when there was a directory **/Developer/Examples/CoreData** on earlier installs of Xcode -- you might not have this, in case you do, looking at it might prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

just put below dode into your Testing Project for test how to increment our counter.

From That code you will get the idea what you need to do and change this code as per you want.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    int count;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    count = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
    NSLog(@"counter is >>>>%d",count);
    [prefs setInteger:count forKey:@"integerKey"];

    // code for adding record to core data

    count++;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs1 setInteger:count forKey:@"integerKey"];
    NSLog(@"counter is >>>>%d",count);
}
```